# Is there a way to access Dom outside iframe from element within it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, iframe

[image: The image attached shows DOM structure for the problem statement]

We have a way to Traversing down the DOM through iframes to #btn1 
we can do this by `$('#iframe1').contents().find('#iframe2').contents().find('#btn1')`

I am struggling to traverse moving up the DOM from #btn1 to outside #iframe2

Following code gives me  []. Consider btnElement to be jquery#btn object

```
`btnElement.closest('iframe')`
```

Neither does this works

```
btnElement.parent().parent().parent()
```

Is there a way to access Dom outside iframe2 from btn1??

Note :  All iframes belongs to the same origin. Cross origin is not the concern to me

Answer (score 6):

You can't *traverse* to it, no; the DOM jQuery works with is rooted in the iframe's window.

But that window object has a `parent` property which refers to the parent window. So you can use that to access things in the parent window.

If the parent window also has jQuery loaded, you can use it like this: `parent.$("selector")`.

If the parent window doesn't have jQuery loaded but the iframe does, you can usually look things up in the parent like this: `$(parent.document).find("selector")`, but other uses of jQuery may be squirrelly, best if possible to use the instance of jQuery from the window in which it's loaded.

(You can only do this if the frame and its parent are loaded from the same origin.)

---

Re your comment:

> Only thing given to me is. jquery object of btn1. How can I find out its parent iframe element. ?
>
> I want to access DOM outside this iframe Say for e.g. I want to know current iframe's parent div

I don't believe there's any direct way to do that, no, you have to hunting: The button element inside the jQuery object (e.g., `btn1[0]`) has a property called `ownerDocument`, which will be `=== (theWindowThatContainsIt).document`. iframe elements have a `contentDocument` property which refers to the same thing. So you use `parent` to get the parent window, then find all the `iframe`s in it, and select the one that has `.contentDocument === btn[0].ownerDocument`:

```
var btn1 = $("#btn");
var doc = btn1[0].ownerDocument;
var iframe = $(parent.document).find("iframe").filter(function() {
    return this.contentDocument === doc;
});
if (iframe.length) {
    // We have the `iframe` element. To get its parent, we'd use
    // `iframe.parent()`. Let's give it a green border:
    iframe.parent().css("border", "1px solid green");
}
```

Comment: Everything is loaded from the same origin

Comment: Challenge 1) Only thing given to me is.  jquery object of btn1. 
How can I find out its parent iframe element. ?

Comment: @RohitKumar: What do you mean by "its parent iframe element"? Do you mean it's parent *window*, or do you literally mean the iframe element in the parent's parent that contains the window of the current iframe's parent?

Comment: I mean iframe tag.
We can surely reach the body of the current iframe by doiing btnElement.parent().parent()    but adding another parent() like btnElement.parent().parent().parent() will return []

Comment: @RohitKumar: I don't believe there's any *direct* way to do that, no, you have to hunting: The button element inside the jQuery object (e.g., `btn1[0]`) has a property called `ownerDocument`, which will be `=== (theWindowThatContainsIt).document`. `iframe` elements have a `contentDocument` property which refers to the same thing. So you use `parent` to get the parent window, then find all the iframes in it, and select the one that has `.contentDocument === btn[0].ownerDocument`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102625/discussion-between-rohit-kumar-and-t-j-crowder).

Comment: @RohitKumar: I don't do the chat thing when it's germane to the question, I think it's dumb (of SO management) to separate things like that.

Comment: Thats not my requirement. I want to access DOM outside this iframe 
Say for e.g. I want to know current iframe's parent div

Comment: @RohitKumar: You still have to find the iframe first. Then it's just the parent of that.

Comment: @RohitKumar: I've updated the answer with that explanation, and with code.

Comment: yes Agree btn[0].ownerDocument gives a Document object. and if I try to acces its parent() it gives [].. Still not able to accesss the iframe2 or its attributes. Do you see any other way to do it?

Comment: @RohitKumar: I didn't say you'd use `ownerDocument` directly. As I said (and showed with code), you have to match up the `iframe`'s `contentDocument` with the button's `ownerDocument`.